# Javascript ternary w/ for loop error; "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ternary

I am unable to figure out why I cannot use my for loop inside a ternary operation. Here is the code that is not working:

```
this.ask = function() {
  m = (isVoice) ? 'voice' : 'text';
  switch (true) {
    case m == 'voice' && typeof questions[timer.question].voice == 'string':
      (++timer.attempts > timer.maxAttempts) ?
        console.log('Stop'):
        console.log('Play file (' + timer.attempts + '): ' + questions[timer.question].voice);
      break;
    case m == 'voice' && typeof questions[timer.question].voice == 'object':
      (++timer.attempts > timer.maxAttempts) ?
        console.log('Stop'):
        for (i = 0; i < questions[timer.question].voice.length; i++) {
          console.log(questions[timer.question].voice[i])
        };
      break;
    default:
      (++timer.attempts > timer.maxAttempts) ?
        console.log('Stop'):
        console.log('Say Text (' + timer.attempts + '): ' + questions[timer.question].text);
      break;
  }
};
```

Specifically the **case where m == 'voice' and typeof == 'object'** throws the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for". If I change that one case to be:

```
case m == 'voice' && typeof questions[timer.question].voice == 'object':
            console.log('Audio, Array.');
            if (++timer.attempts > timer.maxAttempts) {
                console.log('Stop');
            }
            else {
                for (i in questions[timer.question].voice) {
                    console.log(questions[timer.question].voice[i]);
                }
            }
            break;
```

... then everything works as expected.

Why is this??

Comment: In the ternary you need to use expressions that return some value, for loop does not return anything.

Comment: The ternary operator can be very handy but it also leaves a hole open for unreadable spaghetti code. In my humble opinion, this is one of those instances. I would not recommend writing code in this fashion. Use an `if`.

Comment: I went with what many had pointed out... simple if/else statements for cleaner code. Thank you all for the input. Thank you Pointy for explaining what the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for the ternary operator expects that the "branches" are expressions. You can't just put any arbitrary statement there; in JavaScript, a `for` loop is *not* an expression.

You could wrap the loop in a function and call it, but it would be a lot simpler to just use a plain `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap your for loop in parenthesis it might work.

```
function() {
    for (i = 0; i < questions[timer.question].voice.length; i++) {
     console.log(questions[timer.question].voice[i])
    }
}()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

But stylistically you're really pushing the envelope...

Comment: That too is a syntax error. The same one, in fact, and for essentially the same reason. Once you start the statement with `(`, the only thing that can follow is an expression, and `for` is not a token that can start part of an expression.

Comment: Right. As @Pointy states previously the only way one could achieve this would be with an anonymous function immediately executed.